# PDF documents can only be saved, not opened

Tags: firefox, iceweasel

When I click on a PDF link in Iceweasel (Firefox in Debian) there is no option to open the document, only to save it. In Edit -> Preferences -> Applications I have set the action for PDF documents to "Use Atril Document Viewer" but apparently it has no effect. Any clues?

Comment: Is this consistent across multiple sources of PDFs? The server can hide that it's a PDF (by setting content-type to the generic application/octet-stream), or it can explicitly request that the browser not try plugins to view it (content-disposition: attachment).

Comment: You're right, it's only when the response header has content type set to `application/octet-stream`. An with the link I had problem with content disposition was also set to `attachment`. Still the Save dialog says "You have chosen to open ... which is: PDF document", so Iceweasel has identified the file as a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is exactly the same problem, but despite setting the default to open PDFs in an external application, Firefox frequently ignores this, popping up a dialogue box instead of automatically opening the external application.

One solution that worked for me was to install the [Open in Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-browser/) extension, and set it to `Never ask to confirm "Save File" action`. Despite the slightly confusing nomenclature, the next time I attempted to open a PDF, I set it to `Open in browser as PDF`, and `Do this automatically for files like this from now on`. The next time I attempted to open a PDF, it opened automatically without the dialogue box.